# What's the correct RESTful way to structure A Website's Parent/Child Views

Tags: rest, url-routing, parent-child, hierarchy

NOTE: This is not specifically for an API.

I have three Entities: `Building` `Unit` `Person`

These are pure simple easy Exclusive 1:M relationships

A `Person` can only live in (1) unit
A `Unit` can only exist in (1) unit
The `Building` is essentially the parent.

Should I have URLs like:

The View mode is pretty easy

```
/buildings                        //Show all buildings
/buildings/[id]                   //Show one building
/buildings/[id]/units             //Show all units in a building
/buildings/[id]/units/[id]/people //Show all people in a unit
```

However, this seems kind of verbose. While those URLs may work for PUTS and POSTS which redirect to a GET, if I want to show all the units and people in a building, should I be using a route like `buildings/[id]/details` or is there some other standard convention?

Also, when I want to display a form to edit the values, is there a standard url path like `buildings/[id]/edit` A POST and a PUT in this case will essentially be using the same form ( but with the PUT having the fields filled out ) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question may attract some opinionated answers, but it'd be good to hear about other peoples' practices regarding RESTful API designs.

You say your paths seem kind of verbose, and you may feel that way if your IDs are auto incremented integers and the only way to specify buildings, units, etc is with paths like

```
buildings/1/units/4/tenants
buildings/1/units/4/tenants/5
```

To me these are clear interfaces. If I had to maintain your code, I'd think it's pretty obvious what's going on here. If I had to criticize something, I would say you seem to be developing in a way that allows for all or one selection. It's your design choice, though. Maybe that's exactly what you need in this case. Here are some examples that come to mind.

**update one tenant**

```
PUT buildings/1/units/4/tenants/2
```

**create three units**

```
POST buildings/2/units                 //carries message body for SQL in back end
```

**read tenants with certain criteria**

```
GET buildings/1/tenants?params=        //GET can't carry a message body
```

**delete tenants with certain criteria**

```
DELETE buildings/5/tenants?criteria=   //params needed?
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes about the design choice. In your first example, that's exactly the kind of thing that I'm talking about. I'm leaning towards just doing a PUT to `units/4/tenants/2` as the `tenant` entity doesn't have "knowledge" of the grandparent, only its parent the `Unit`. and if the parent Unit ID is changed, do I "Move" the tenant to the other entity? I'm trying to find a few good examples out there to see what works for an API, but there is, as you said, differing opinions.

Comment: @Armstrongest Are you familiar with Trello? It was released by Joel Spolsky, co-creator of Stack Overflow. You're looking for good examples - I suggest you check out the Trello API, for example the boards API -  https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/board and you will see how they've designed their API... it's similar to yours and rich with many examples I believe you will find it helpful. And for that matter, check the Stack Overflow API for even more examples - https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out

Comment: Regarding your first comment, if you only need to update the tenant, why use a path for the buildling and unit at all? To me, this implies some combination key exists in the backend such that your tenant is unique based on the unit ID and the tenant ID. If you have a table of tenants independent of units and buildings, then I would guess each tenant has a unique ID independent of the building and unit they are in. If that's true, then a simpler path of `/tentant/[id]` would be less verbose.

Comment: That's true, it's verbose. I guess I see it both ways. Tenants are exclusive childs of a unit. If a unit gets deleted, all tenants do as well.  If I'm doing a POST to `/tenant/` I want my controller to add the tenant to a `unit` but need to include it in the POST data. If I `POST /unit/[uid]/tenant/[id]` data is in the URL. However, I realize there is a dependency created on `unit` I also inherently know the *grand-parent* `building` and can send back a `302` to load that page after data was added without a db query. Hmmm... I do see your point though. K.I.S.S., right?